# record voice in vxml (Tellme studio developer account)

Tags: xml, ivr, vxml

I have developer account in tell studio ,

I tried some basic snippet its working fine, finaly i tried record tag,

but its not working , eve NOINPUT TAG also not working ,

This is my snippet ,

```
 <vxml version="2.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/vxml">
   <form id="form-record">
     <record name="greeting" beep="true" maxtime="10s" finalsilence="2000ms">
       <prompt> 
         Please record your greeting after the tone.---------------This line executing
       </prompt> 
       <noinput> 
         i did not hear anything. <reprompt/> ------this line not working, 
       </noinput> 
     </record>
     <field name="confirm" type="boolean">
       <prompt>
         your greeting is <audio expr="greeting"/> 
         to keep it say yes, to discard it say no.
       </prompt>
       <filled>
         <if cond="confirm">
           <prompt> ok, i will save your greeting </prompt>
           <submit method="post" namelist="greeting"
             next="greetingstore.jsp"/>
         <else/> 
           <prompt> ok, lets try again </prompt>
           <clear namelist="greeting confirm"/>
         </if>
       </filled>
     </field> 
   </form>
 </vxml>
```

Comment: Is your test case only involving silence or actual recordings ?  If so, does it properly timeout in 2 seconds and reprompt or go onto the confirm with 2 seconds of silence in recording ?  On some systems, it doesn't take much noise for the system to think there's audio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you keep quiet around telephone?

"record" can gathering very small noise.

Please press mute button of your telephone.

Comment: Maybe"2 seconds of silence" is "finalsilence"?